# Dojox/app for desktop applications. (Dojo 1.9)

Tags: javascript, dojo

So far in my Dojo web applications I have handled the main application flow by separating all of the high level views (ex: home, search page, admin page, etc) into widgets and changing views by adding them to a all-encompassing widget that contains the entire application and swapping out the display css property ('none', 'block') of the high-level view widgets.

This works, but seems clunky.

I have started looking into dojox/app, but it seems more suited for mobile development. 
From the [dojo reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/app.html):

> dojox/app is an application framework designed to simply configure through a configuration file an application formed of potentially nested views and to facilitate the transitioning between those views based. **Its main current targets are mobile (phone & tablet) devices but it is not restricted to this and can be used for desktop applications as well**. Thanks to dojox/app the applications are easily configurable and buildable for easy and fast deployment

Perhaps someone with experience could lay out some pros and cons for using Dojox/app in desktop applications running in the browser? 
Or other more formal alternatives to handling this (view switching in particular) manually?

Comment: I used something like this with webos(enyo), actually liked it, its good at making stacks of your views and having the ability to move back and forth from the stack.  The only reason we did not use it in our current project is that we needed a header and footer that remained during all page changes.

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this, I'm also investegating best practice and solutions within the dojo framework for the same purpose as you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason (I think) that the `dojox/app` library mainly focuses on the mobile aspect is because the mobile community actually needs it more than a desktop environment. Usually when developing mobile apps you will use a multi-page structure due to the screen size (for example a list page, a detail page, ...). While desktop applications can rely on using a single page (and then the **dojox/mvc** framework alone will work as well).

The **dojox/app** library includes many application level APIs, such as navigating between pages (controllers/views) while **dojox/mvc** mainly focuses on the Model, View, Controller part.

However, dojox/app will work fine on a desktop environment, the most important change will probably just be the view, but the technology behind it doesn't change.

---

If you're looking for a list of pros/cons I cannot give those, the only thing I can come up with is that there are not a lot of examples on the web about using dojox/app on a desktop environment. Even the reference guide is not up to date (as it is still using data stores which are deprecated).

---

I don't think there are other alternatives inside the Dojo toolkit (certainly not if you're looking for view switching), you could use dojox/mvc but it means you will have to do more things by yourself. But there are plenty of JavaScript MVC frameworks on the web (AngularJS, Ember.js).